# How to compare id with Foreign Key

Tags: android

I want one to many relatioship in android with Sqlite like a student_table is in Realtion with student_informaion table. Values of student_table are populated in Listview and when a particular student name is clicked,the respective information should be shown in next Listview.

Till now what I have done

MainActivity

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor getid=database.getId(); //loading ids to cursor

                ArrayList<Integer> Get_Id = new ArrayList<>();
                Intent content = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                if (getid!= null && getid.getCount()>0){
                    getid.moveToFirst();
                    do{
                        Get_Id.add(getid.getInt(getid.getColumnIndex("COL1_ID"))); //loading ids to arrays
                    }
                    while(getid.moveToNext());
                }

                    content.putExtra("KEY", Get_Id); //passing ids to next activity
                    startActivityForResult(content,0);
```

Second Activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //getting intent
            if(extras!=null) {
                int [] ids = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("KEY");
                Cursor data =db.rawQuery("select COL3_AYAH  from " + TABLE2_NAME + " where " + COL2_FK+ "=='" + ids + "'" , null);  //selection query
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

                    while (data.moveToNext()) {
                        list.add(data.getString(1)); //adding resultant data to listview


                    }
                    ListAdapter listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                    lv.setAdapter(listadapter);
```

Exception details:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: COL1_ID (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: select COL1_ID from Surah_Name, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:925)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:536)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1397)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
        at com.hukm_e_azan.al_madrasa.Database.getId(Database.java:82)
        at com.hukm_e_azan.al_madrasa.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:53)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:321)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1217)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3203)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4151)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
2019-01-23 15:08:42.577 29192-29192/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hukm_e_azan.al_madrasa, PID: 29192
```

Comment: "_But my app is not working_" - Please try to be more specific

Comment: hey there! actullay im trying to make a one to many relationship like between  student table and student_information table.All i want is when user click on  particular student in listview, it should display the information in next listview.

Answer (score 0):

You have seem to be passing the integer array directly to the query. Try looping around the array so you can use the actual indexes. (Unless you have an error at some other point like in the query itself or having the extras as null, this should work.)

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //getting intent
            if(extras!=null) {
                int [] ids = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("KEY");

                // get each ID from the loop and use it for separate queries
                for (int id : ids) {
                    Cursor data =db.rawQuery("select COL3_AYAH  from " + TABLE2_NAME + " where " + COL2_FK+ "='" + id + "'" , null);  //selection query
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

                    while (data.moveToNext()) {
                        list.add(data.getString(1)); //adding resultant data to listview


                    }
                }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but it is still not working.here is my query for creating table in database,   db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE2_NAME+"(CONTENT_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,Ayah TEXT, Foreign_key INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(Foreign_key) REFERENCES Surah_Name (TITLE_ID))");

Comment: I've edited my answer, in queries you shouldn't be using double equals to check variables, one equals is enough. The error I believe lies down at `"select COL3_AYAH  from " + TABLE2_NAME + " where " + COL2_FK+ "='" + id + "'" , null`

Comment: thanks, i have corrected it as well but still app crashes again.

Comment: Then I need the exception details to be able to fix the issue. Please post in the question itself by editing.